# Transform HTML text into input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

Consider a standard web page created with PHP passing some text variables, taken from a database, to an HTML file.

I would like to be able to modify the value of the variables using as an interface the real HTML file (so one can actually see where the variables are in the page).

I tried simply using a substitution like "`$variable --> < input value="'.$variable.'"/>`". This works only in some cases. For example it doesn't work if the variable is the content on an `<a>` tag or if the variable contains some HTML.

Do you have any suggestion on how I could accomplish this? Is there a way to force `<input>` tags anywhere in my HTML file, so that they can be seen from the end user?

Comment: Look at htmlspecialchars() : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: @JoshKG the problem is not what's inside the variable, but what is outside, in the html document.

Comment: look into http://www.tinymce.com/ but have it target the input tags, then strip away what you don't want from it.

Comment: to show HTML tags to an end user and NOT have it rendered by the browser as actual code, wrap the outer HTML with htmlspecialchars()

Comment: @JoshKG I would like to render the html with the browser, having an input field wherever there is a variable

Comment: are you using inputs because you want the end user to be able to edit the variables and post them back to the db?

Comment: @marcosh Let's say you have on your HTML page (rendered by a PHP script) an article with three elements - title, content and author; and you would like to show an input (or textarea) on click or some other event, or maybe by default; am i right?

Comment: @hex494D49 I was thinking to di it by default, but actually also on a click would be nice

Comment: You'll need to strip tags then from your variables, and then add them back in in your PHP form processing code

Comment: @marcosh Check my answer. In a meantime I'll add another way how to edit content.

Comment: @hex494D49 in the end I completely changed my approach to the problem, also due to a change of requests from the end-users

Answer (score 0):

This is the default and the easiest way to edit your variables (content of your site)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Edit</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $title = "Lorem Ipsum";
    $content = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <strong>Lorem Ipsum</strong> has been the industry's <a href=\"http://justin-bieber.com\">standard dummy</a> text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
<pre>function toggle(o) {
    var e = document.getElementById(o);
    e.style.display = (e.style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : '' );
}</pre>";
    $author = "Anonymous";
?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="_URL_">
        <label>Tilte</label><br /><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo  stripslashes($title) ?>" /><br />
        <label>Content</label><br /><textarea name="content"><?php echo stripslashes($content) ?></textarea><br />
        <label>Author</label><br /><input type="text" name="author" value="<?php echo  stripslashes($author) ?>" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```